# Simple onclick button not functioning in android

Tags: java, android

I have a following snippet of codes. What I want to  do is that when I click button1 just show the text. But eclipse suggest me to add `onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)` but then at `btnOk.setOnClickListener(oclBtnOk);` it gives me this error:

> The method setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener) in the type View is not applicable for the arguments (DialogInterface.OnClickListener)

Here is my code:

```
TextView tvOut;
    Button btnOk;
    Button btnCancel;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                    .commit();
        }

        tvOut = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        btnOk = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        btnCancel = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);


     // create click listener
        OnClickListener oclBtnOk = new OnClickListener() {
          public void onClick(View v) {
            // change text of the TextView (tvOut)
            tvOut.setText("Button OK clicked");
          }

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }



        };
        // assign click listener to the OK button (btnOK)
        btnOk.setOnClickListener(oclBtnOk);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are importing the wrong `OnClickListener` class.

[`View.setOnClickListener()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setOnClickListener%28android.view.View.OnClickListener%29) Takes a `View.OnClickListener`, not a `DialogInterface.OnClickListener`, which is what you have imported.

If you *don't* use the `DialogInterface.OnClickListener` elsewhere in this class, simply change your import statement to import `android.view.View.OnClickListener`.

If you *do* also use the `DialogInterface.OnClickListener` interface in your class, you will need to further qualify the class name here, like so:

```
View.OnClickListener oclBtnOk = new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // change text of the TextView (tvOut)
        tvOut.setText("Button OK clicked");
    }
}
```

You should also remove the `onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)` method, as that is only defined for `DialogInterface.OnClickListener`.

Comment: Ok I will try it soon. But what is this dialog interface is it for the pop-up

Comment: There are a number of Dialog classes that use it, such as [AlertDialog](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.html). Usually it is used for callbacks when the user presses a button in a Dialog.

Comment: I have put this codes View.OnClickListener oclBtnOk = new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // change text of the TextView (tvOut)
                tvOut.setText("Button OK clicked");
            }
        };
        btnOk.setOnClickListener(oclBtnOk); and when I try to run my app it say unfortunately it stopped. Is a very simple code what could be wrong?

Comment: Your logcat should show a complete stacktrace that tells you exactly what went wrong.

Comment: Yes I can see which cause I find it have so many lines in the logcat. When I comment this codes the app run so is definitely something wrong here.

Comment: It has these 06-18 15:15:52.662: E/AndroidRuntime(1587): FATAL EXCEPTION: main, 06-18 15:15:52.662: E/AndroidRuntime(1587): Process: com.example.my1, PID: 1587,06-18 15:15:52.662: E/AndroidRuntime(1587): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.my1/com.example.my1.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException,06-18 15:15:52.662: E/AndroidRuntime(1587):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195),06-18 15:15:52.662: E/AndroidRuntime(1587):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)

Comment: My guess is that `tvOut` is null. You can put a breakpoint at `tvOut.setText()` to verify this. Make sure that your `activity_main` layout contains a TextView with id `textView1`. Also check out [Unfortunately MyApp has stopped. How can I solve this?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this)

Comment: The tvOut have a value <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

Comment: And is that in your `activity_main` layout XML file? If so, then put a breakpoint in `onCreate` and step through your code until you find what is causing the NullPointerException.

Comment: Yes its in my fragment_main.xml. I have now created toggle breakpoint. I run yet the same it stopped.

Comment: You just pointed out the problem- you said it is in your `fragment_main`. I asked if it was in `activity_main`. From what I see in your code, the `fragment_main` layout isn't being used at all.

Comment: I am a bit lost now which layout is used cause I read the main just for reference is it? I tried to change to this now setContentView(R.layout.fragment_main); also the same. But why even with activity_main when I commented my codes all my button n text view appear?

Comment: It sounds like you need to create a new SO question that addresses your NullPointerException specifically. This is getting a bit too involved for the comment section.

Comment: Ok I will create a new one now. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem :
The method setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener) in the type View is not applicable for the arguments (DialogInterface.OnClickListener)

calButton.setOnClickListener(addClick);

Source:

```
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

LinearLayout layout1;
EditText no1Text,no2Text;
Button calButton;
TextView answerText;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    layout1=new LinearLayout(this);


    no1Text=new EditText(this);
    no2Text=new EditText(this);
    calButton=new Button(this);
    answerText=new TextView(this);

    answerText.setText("0");
    calButton.setText("Calculate");

    layout1.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

    calButton.setOnClickListener(addClick);

    layout1.addView(no1Text);
    layout1.addView(no2Text);
    layout1.addView(calButton);
    layout1.addView(answerText);


    setContentView(layout1);
}


private OnClickListener addClick=new OnClickListener() 
{

    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) 
    {

        String firstStr=no1Text.getText().toString();
        String secondStr=no2Text.getText().toString();


        double firstNo=Double.parseDouble(firstStr);
        double secondNo=Double.parseDouble(secondStr);

        double sumNo=firstNo+secondNo;

        String sumStr=String.valueOf(sumNo);

        answerText.setText(sumStr);
    }
};
}
```